# Getting different output for slight variation in input for unicode.IsNumber() function in Go

Tags: go, unicode, truncation

Why does unicode.IsNumber(rune(truncfloat)) returns false some cases?

For 55.3 output is true
For 58.3 output is false

Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    var truncint int
    var truncfloat float64

    fmt.Printf("Enter a floating point number: ")
    num, err := fmt.Scan(&truncfloat)

    if unicode.IsNumber(rune(truncfloat)) {
        truncint = int(truncfloat)
        fmt.Printf("Trucated number is: %d", truncint)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Recieved %d numbers, Error: %s", num, err)
    }
}
```

Following are test cases with Execution output:

```
PS C:\learngo> .\trunc.exe
Enter a floating point number: 58.3
Recieved 1 numbers, Error: %!s(<nil>)
PS C:\learngo> .\trunc.exe
Enter a floating point number: 55.3
Trucated number is: 55
```

Comment: `rune` is a built in alias for `int32` so `unicode.IsNumber` is receiving the `int32` values `55` and `58` respectively. 55 (decimal) is the character `7` and 58 is the character `:`, so `55` is indeed a number, and 58 is not. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do with your code, but you aren't doing anything particularly sensible.

Comment: Can you please explain in your own language what you hoped to check using `unicode.IsNumber()` ? I have the feeling your expectation doesn't match what this function actually does.

Answer (score 0):

The function `unicode.IsNumber()` expects a rune, such as `'0'` or `'9'`. While you do indeed pass a rune, the contained value is just whatever code point 55 and 58 map to. You will find out which by adding:

```golang
fmt.Println(string(rune(truncfloat)))
```

This will print `7` for `55` and `:` for `58`. `:` is not a number, so your check fails.

What you actually want to do is to cast to `int` instead of `rune` (because you care about the integer value of the result, not its Unicode code point) and do your number check before the cast instead (since `int` cannot hold values which are not a number (NaN)).

```golang
if math.IsNaN(truncfloat) {
    fmt.Println("Entered float is not a number")
    return
}
if truncfloat > math.MaxInt || truncfloat < math.MinInt {
    fmt.Println("Entered float is outside of int range")
    return
}
truncint = int(truncfloat)
fmt.Printf("Truncated number is: %d", truncint)
```